# How to make 'intelligent' key mappings in Vim?

Tags: vim, dry

At present I have the following mappings in my Vimrc:

```
" Quick Buffer switch mappings {{{
" The idea is to press <leader> and then the number from normal mode to switch
" e.g. `,2` would switch to the second buffer (listed at the top of the
" airline strip
nnoremap <Leader>1 :1b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>2 :2b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>3 :3b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>4 :4b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>5 :5b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>6 :6b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>7 :7b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>8 :8b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>9 :9b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>10 :10b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>11 :11b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>12 :12b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>13 :13b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>14 :14b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>15 :15b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>16 :16b<CR>

" Quick Buffer wipe/delete keys. Press <Leader> and then d and buffer number
" e.g. `,d2` would wipe buffer 2

nnoremap <Leader>d1 :Bdelete 1<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d2 :Bdelete 2<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d3 :Bdelete 3<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d4 :Bdelete 4<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d5 :Bdelete 5<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d6 :Bdelete 6<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d7 :Bdelete 7<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d8 :Bdelete 8<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d9 :Bdelete 9<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d10 :Bdelete 10<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d11 :Bdelete 11<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d12 :Bdelete 12<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d13 :Bdelete 13<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d14 :Bdelete 14<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d15 :Bdelete 15<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d16 :Bdelete 16<CR>
" }}}
```

They work great but I can't help thinking this should be smarter/DRYer in the vimrc. What about if I open a buffer with number 17 for example.

Is there a way of intelligently mapping these so that a user could enter  and then any buffer number to have the buffer open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use meta-programming with `:execute` to automate the creation of those mappings:

```
for i in range(1, 99)
    execute printf('nnoremap <Leader>%d :%db<CR>', i, i)
endfor
```

It is also possible to define a single mapping (with just a prefix), that then queries the number via `getchar()`. The challenge here is to determine when to end this, something that you get for free (due to `'timeout'`) with the separate mappings. That's why I would prefer the first solution here.

Answer (score 3):

`<c-6>` switches to the previous buffer. However you can also provide a count which will be used to switch to that buffer. E.g. `6<c-6>` is equivalent to  `:b 6`.

I still can't help but think these buffer commands are a bit awkward because have to keep buffer numbers and files straight in your head. I think using some of `:b` native features could be of some help to you:

- `:b` command can take a partial filenames. e.g. `:b foo`
- `:b` can use globs so you can add some fuzziness. e.g. `:b foo*bar.c`
- `<tab>` to complete the filenames
- `<c-d>` for listing out the buffer names
- split with the `:sb` command which takes all the same arguments as `:b`

I find `:bdelete` a bit dangerous they way you have it. I would suggest you just switch to a buffer and then do `:bd` to delete the current buffer. However `:bd` can take partial filenames and globs as well just like `:b`.

I have also seen `~/.vimrc` files where people use a mapping to call `:ls` and then start the prompt with `:b`. Think of more of a menu based approach.

```
nnoremap <leader>b :ls<cr>:b<space>
```

For more help see:

```
:h ctrl-6
:h :b
:h :sb
:h :bd
:h :ls
```

Comment: How did I forget `<C-^>` took a count?

Comment: How? Because buffer numbers come and go but filenames stay around and are easier to remember. I also imagine you have a similar workflow to mine where you rarely use buffer numbers. I have also been tinkering around with adding more fuzziness to the buffer commands with my [bumblebee.vim](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-bumblebee) plugin.

Comment: Hehe yes, that wasn't a real question: I never use buffer numbers either.

Comment: Peter - in my case I have airline set up so that open buffers display at the top of my GUI with their buffer number. I can therefore simply look at the buffer I want to open and press `<Leader>1` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different strategy that only uses a single mapping:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <key> :<C-u>try \| execute "b" . v:count \| catch \| endtry<CR>
```

Now you can do `3<key>` to go to buffer number 3. I'll leave it up to you to find the right `<key>`.

Comment: Just tried this but oddly I have to press the key combo twice. My line is `:nnoremap <silent> <Leader> :<C-u>try \| execute "b" . v:count \| catch \| endtry<CR>` - is it because I am using the leader? Also seems to screw up my split windows but that may be unrelated.

Comment: Yes, Vim is waiting for you to type more characters for disambiguation . You should try another key/combo.

Comment: OK, great, think I'll keep this one commented out in the .vimrc just in case. However, I marked Ingo's solution as the answer as it allows me to keep the same key combo's.